# How to disable/avoid Ampersand-Escaping in Java-XML?

Tags: java, xml, dom, escaping, ampersand

I want to create a XML where blanks are replaced by `&#160;`. But the Java-Transformer escapes the Ampersand, so that the output is `&amp;#160;`

Here is my sample code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.newDocument();

        Element element = document.createElement("element");
        element.setTextContent("&#160;");
        document.appendChild(element);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(stream);
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), streamResult);
        System.out.println(stream.toString());

    }

}
```

And this is the output of my sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<element>&amp;#160;</element>
```

Any ideas to fix or avoid that? thanks a lot!

Comment: I wonder why you'd want to replace the blanks. You want to explain that?

Comment: As I understand he wants a non-breaking blank (what exactly 0xA0 is) instead of an ordinary one

Comment: the xml that i create is a xsl-fo-xml where i need the blanks for the block-elements. so blanks are necessary for me, because apache-fop seems to ignore leading-blanks. i got the advice elsewhere to replace blanks with this entity. andrei is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the text content directly to the character you want, and the serializer will escape it for you if necessary:

```
element.setTextContent("\u00A0");
```

Comment: This way there's no escaping since 0xA0 isn't a special character for xml. So it may not be what oleh wants.

Comment: well i have accepted the answer because it worked for me. although you are right, that it was not the answer i truly looked for.

Comment: @oleh this is what you needed. If you really, realy, really want the non breaking space esacped, then set the encoding to `US-ASCII`, or write your own serializer.

Answer (score 7):

Use output escaping as follows:

```
Node disableEscaping = document.createProcessingInstruction(StreamResult.PI_DISABLE_OUTPUT_ESCAPING, "&");
 Element element = document.createElement("element");
 element.setTextContent("&#160;");
 document.appendChild(disableEscaping );
 document.appendChild(element);
Node enableEscaping = document.createProcessingInstruction(StreamResult.PI_ENABLE_OUTPUT_ESCAPING, "&");
document.appendChild(enableEscaping )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
element.appendChild (document.createCDATASection ("&#160;"));
```

instead of

```
element.setTextContent(...);
```

You'll get this in your xml: 
It may work if I understand correctly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I tried your advice, it do not work for me. the generated character-data `<![CDATA[&#160;]]>` made me some troubles in my further code, i will look if I can handle this later.

Comment: After some tries, the result of this way is the same as simple Text-Node. The Text `&#160;` is being handled as separated characters instead of one entity. so the further processing lead to `$amp;#160;`.

Answer (score 0):

As addon to forty-two's answer:

If, like me, you're trying the code in a *non-patched* Eclipse IDE, you're likely to see some weird A's appearing instead of the non-breaking space. This is because of the encoding of the console in Eclipse not matching Unicode (UTF-8).

Adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to your eclipse.ini should solve this.

Cheers,
Wim