# exporting the &-sign to xml from java

Tags: java, xml, export, ampersand

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable/avoid Ampersand-Escaping in Java-XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469202/how-to-disable-avoid-ampersand-escaping-in-java-xml)

i need to create something like: `&#8743;`(in the xml-file) and the problem is, that the java technique i am using convertes it to `&amp;#8743;` what doesn´t work for me. i need it in the first format. so, the question is, is there a way to escape it in some way or whatever to get it like that: `&#8743;`?
for the exporting i am using the same method as here: [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/)

Comment: Please show us your code fragment, and we'll help you correct it.

Comment: i am using the method i have linked. -__-
this project is big. but it works in the same way as on the linked page. i am using this: `tag.setAttribute("defaultText", "&#8743;");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = f.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document d = builder.newDocument();
    Element root = d.createElement("root");
    d.appendChild(root);
    root.setTextContent("this text contains the \u2227 character");

    Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "US-ASCII");
    t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    t.transform(new DOMSource(d), new StreamResult(System.out));
```

which produces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII" standalone="no"?>
<root>this text contains the &#8743; character</root>
```

Comment: yeah, but i need it for a tag and not the text between the tags. perhaps it works there, also. i ll try it tomorrow!

Comment: Huh? For a tag? Do you mean for an attribute?

Comment: Well, it works the same for attributes. Try it!

Comment: nice. will try it tomorrow... thanks

Comment: OK, but now that you have 42 reputation, the time is ripe ;-)

Comment: i don´t get what you mean :)
can´t test it right now, because i do not have the project with me. but tomorrow. and if it works, i mark your answer...

Comment: as you said. it works. so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is using `&amp;`. Typically it works. If it does not work for your please post some code snippets.

Comment: Or in other words: when parsing an XML document which contains "&amp;#8743;" with a proper XML parser will return "&#8743;" again.

Comment: now it doesn´t work. if it would work, i wouldn´t ask. `&amp;#8743;` gets to `&amp;amp;#8743;`

Comment: And yet in other words: an XML document which contains "&#8743;" is not a valid XML document, AFAIK.

Comment: Please show the relevant code, as suggested.

Comment: how the user should enter the sign that is not on the keyboard? `&#8743;` is valid xml

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it's valid: http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-references
Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're trying to encode the XML by hand.

Try:

- Convert the user input to Java String
- Let the XML library take care of converting from Java String to XML String

Comment: this post is senseless XD. how to pass something other than a string to the `tag.setAttribute()` method than a string?

Comment: @immerhart according to forty-two's response, "&#8743" in XSD is equal to "\u2227" in Java. So, make sure you use the Java character encoding, not the XSD character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Document doc = documentBuilder.newDocument();
Element root= doc.createElement("root");
doc.appendChild(root);

Document newDoc = documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("<element defaulttext=\"&#8743;\">some text or XML</element>")));

Element newElement = newDoc.getDocumentElement();
Node node = doc.importNode(newElement, true);

root.appendChild(node);
```